# Multi monitor setup issues with primary display

Tags: 18.04

new user here. I'm having issues for the past two days with setting up my monitors. I'm using 3 monitors (2 displays and 1 huion drawing screen tablet). I had setup inside arandr my primary display and also in ubuntu settings. After logging out or restarting the pc the primary display gets transferred to the huion display instead of the monitor I use normally.anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1229687/edit) your question with the following information? 1) What graphics card is your computer using, and what version of drivers are installed? You can find this by running `lshw -c video` in terminal and pasting the output into the question. 2) How long has this been happening? 3) Are you able to verify that this is an Ubuntu only problem?

Comment: I'm using a geforce1050ti card with standard drivers.this happened when I installed the third monitor.im not in front of my pc now but as I remember it standard was 454 I think. I could be of better help later once I get home!